# spyder ctrl + click not working

Tags: spyder

I'm using anaconda with python3 on ubuntu, and created a new env with python2, in the new env, I also installed spyder, but with the spyder, I can't "go to definition" with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click shortcut, can anyone help me? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click shortcut does not work only for a specific package that I imported of which the path was added in the scripts manually, so spyder cannot find the package path without running it, so just add the path to PYTHONPATH manager in the spyder IDE, then the problem resolved.